# How to renumber pages in an Oracle APEX application?

Tags: oracle-apex

I've just finished my first "real" APEX app but it's looking a bit messy. Is there any way I can renumber the pages so that they're back in order of the application flow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Numbers are arbitrary. Don't go to the hassle of renumbering everything, as you'll need to test all the branches, tabs, breadcrumbs....

Comment: Unfortunately the page numbers are heavily exposed in the appex. For example pages are sorted by default by their ID on App view. Or in the debugger the pages are referred by IDs only. So It is very unfortunate that renumbering them is so painful...

Answer (score 10):

1. Copy the page in question and set the new number
2. Change any references leading to the old page to the new page
3. Delete the old page

Answer (score 5):

The following advice won't help you much with your current application, but I find it useful to plan out the general page numbering in advance.

I start by splitting my application into groups of pages, say, Accounting, Reports and Administration, and then assign 100 (or 1000) pages to each of those groups.

For example:

```
100 - Accounting (main page)
200 - Reports (main page)
300 - Administration (main page)
```

Then I assign sub-pages within each group, based on which pages my requirement analysis tells me I will likely need:

```
100 - Accounting (main page)
110 - List Invoices
120 - Edit Invoice
121 - Edit Invoice - Details Screen
130 - Add new invoice - step 1
131 - Add new invoice - step 2
132 - Add new invoice - step 3 
200 - Reports (main page)
300 - Administration (main page)
```

And so on, you get the idea. Leave some room between the numbers (110, 120, etc.) to be able to add a few pages later.

Of course, it's difficult to plan everything out in advance, so some out-of-place page numbers pages will have to be used after a while, but in my experience a bit of up-front planning makes it much more manageable (and easy to work with).

Answer (score 3):

1. As Gary suggests, it's better to consider page numbers to be arbitrary.
2. You could export the application, edit the SQL script with the new page numbers (remembering to search for all locations where a page number is referenced), then re-import the application - and test it thoroughly :) - hopefully you don't have references to the pages in other applications though :)
3. In Apex 3.2 and later you can put your pages into Groups, which can be useful for sorting the pages out and make it easier to find the page you're interested in.

Comment: 3.2, that is old... but I feel I should reference my thoughts on this for future readers http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2016/05/apex-page-numbering.html

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Create a copy of a page(s)

[image: see how to copy a page]

**Step 2:** And delete your previous page(s).

And Here you go.
But, you'll need to test all the branches, tabs, breadcrumbs etc.

If you are willing to do this, I will suggest you to go through your order of page creation (means, create a copy of first page that you've created at the start of your application). It will help you to get hint which branches,tabs,breadcrumbs needs to be update.